# Draggable component that is larger than JFrame (JScrollPane with invisble scrollbars on each side)

Tags: java, swing, draggable, jscrollpane

I have created a draggable JComponent in Java Swing and want to display it bigger than the JFrame it contains is (it's supposed to be a game map, movable by drag&drop). As i found didn't find a way to display the component alone bigger than the frame, I tried to put it into a JScrollPane and remove the horizontal as well as the vertical scrollbar, but Eclipse says "invalid verticalScrollBarPolicy". Is there a workaround for that or - even better - a way to scale my Draggable JComponent to a size greater than the JFrame without having to add it to extra panels or components?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to put it into a JScrollPane and remove the horizontal as well as the vertical scrollbar, but Eclipse says "invalid verticalScrollBarPolicy".

Make sure you use the proper variables:

```
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

> a way to scale my Draggable JComponent to a size greater than the JFrame

Implement the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the appropriate size of your component.

Comment: thanks, I wrote "scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);, shame on me. Thanks for the helpful replies though!

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own reusable, draggable component by implementing MouseMotionListener in a JPanel. You will have to keep track of the mouse position, image and panel dimensions, and the current offset of the image you wish to display.

```
private Image image;
private int imageWidth, imageHeight, width, height;
private int mouseX, mouseY;
private int offsetX, offsetY;
```

Implement the mouseMoved method to simply track the mouse position.

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
{
    mouseX = e.getX();
    mouseY = e.getY();
}
```

In the mouseDragged method, update the offset to reflect the change in position.

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
{
    int mx = e.getX();
    int my = e.getY();
    offsetX += (mouseX - mx);
    offsetY += (mouseY - my);
    // don't let offset exceed bounds of image
    offsetX = Math.max(offsetX, 0);
    offsetX = Math.min(offsetX, imageWidth - width);
    offsetY = Math.max(offsetY, 0);
    offsetY = Math.min(offsetY, imageHeight - height);
    mouseX = mx;
    mouseY = my;
    repaint();
}
```

Finally, override the paint method to display the image at the correct offset.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(image, -offsetX, -offsetY, this);
}
```

Remember to add itself as a mouseMotionListener in the constructor!

```
this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
```

Comment: Also consider `Point#translate()`

Comment: thanks for that, but I already have the draggable component, what I wanted to know is if I can scale the component (extends JComponent) to be larger than the frame it is in